# PHP session_id changes between pages or when refreshing the page

Tags: php, session

The problem is that every time I refresh the page or when I change the page to another one, the session_id changes and new session file is created in session_save_path.
Here is the initial part of my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo session_id();
    ...
?>
```

Obviously the session variables (which is the thing that I need) don't work.

A curious thing is that the page works fine on localhost but doesn't work when I try it on the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check `session_start()` is called on **every** page. We cant see that from here. Also use the `{}` button for styling code.

Comment: session_start() is called on every page. (Thanks for the advice with { })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this setting in your server: `session.auto_start`

This will cause session to be autostarted in each page whether you call `session_start()` or not.

Make sure that there are no phantom `CRLFs` or such stuff before session starts. In production the error_reporting can be off so it might not get caught, but the session might find difficulty getting written. This can sometimes cause this.

Comment: There were phantom CRLFs on my index.php. Removing them has solved mi problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

On your server, in `php.ini` check TTL for your cookies. `session.cookie_lifetime` defines how long the cookie will last in seconds (default is 0, which means until the browser is closed) and `session.gc_maxlifetime` defines how long before the data is deleted, also in seconds.

And make sure the session file isn't stored in a `/tmp` folder.

Comment: `session.cookie_lifetime` value is 0 and `session.gc_maxlifetime` value is 1440. Also, the session file is stored in a folder created by me that isn't temporal.

Comment: Use [`session_get_cookie_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-get-cookie-params.php) to get your cookie parameters and see if everything is ok under `domain`, `secure` and `httponly`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your directory with sessions is not writable.

That's why php generates a new session file each time.
Check your chmod for sessions folder.

Comment: I'm using "is_writable(session_save_path())" to check it. Yes, it's writable.